# ggplot using confidence from mean and se

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 50 treatments and six bags in each treatment for each of the two replications.  I have pasted first few lines of the calculations for the mean, sd and se.

```
>df
Treatment       Rep  mean      sd     se
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 N1      1  25.2   0.5    0.25 
 2 N1      2  24.5   2.38   1.19 
 3 N2     1  26.2   2.63   1.31 
 4 N2     2  24.8   1.71   0.854
 5 N3    1 NaN   NaN     NA    
 6 N3     2 NaN   NaN     NA    
 7 N4     1  31.5   0.707  0.354
 8 N4    2 NaN   NaN     NA    
 9 N5     1  26    NA     NA    
10 N5     2  26.8   2.22   1.11
```

I am trying to make a bar plot with confidence interval error bars using:

```
p<- ggplot(data=df,aes(reorder(Treatment, mean, sum), mean, group = 1))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black", fill="grey", width = 1) + geom_errorbar(aes(x=Treatment, ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se), width = 0.25, color = "black") + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 40)) + theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 5.5, angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = "black",face = "bold")) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size= 8, hjust = 1, colour = "black",face = "bold"))
```

But I get an error and most of the values are not included in the plot. I will appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bar plots aka "dynamite plots" are almost always bad idea. They hide the distribution of the data while using up as much or more ink as other, much better data visualization techniques, see: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4406565/.

You'd be better of plotting your raw data with boxplots/violin plots/cloud plots, etc... It's actually easier to plot boxplots and violin plots in `ggplot2` than it is to plot bar plots, and for a good reason. For a tutorial on how to make boxplots, see: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

You can display both the raw data and summary information efficiently using overlayed boxplots. For example, to make an overlayed boxplot of the data in the `iris` dataset, you can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: This does seem more appropriate as a comment. I completely agree with it, but it is not a coded answer to the question. You might improve it by offering code that could be used on a grouped set of simulated data

Comment: Okay, fair, should I change it into a comment?